Vaadin 24 build success but execution from command line fails with no DevModeHandlerManager implementation found but but dev server enabled
I am trying to run a vaadin sample test I started from Vaadin's site start project with Maven, Spring Boot and Apache Tomcat.
Running it in Eclipse, it does open the browser without problems and runs the page.
Instead if I build from Eclipse setting Maven Build run configuration I obtain a JAR file with success. But if try to run with java -jar filename.jar --trace , it fails with this error:
2024-05-14T13:30:02.153+02:00 ERROR 21600 --- [           main] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Exception sending context initialized event to listener instance of class [com.vaadin.flow.spring.VaadinServletContextInitializer$CompositeServletContextListener]

java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to initialize com.vaadin.flow.spring.VaadinServletContextInitializer$DevModeServletContextListener
        at com.vaadin.flow.spring.VaadinServletContextInitializer$FailFastServletContextListener.contextInitialized(VaadinServletContextInitializer.java:199) ~[vaadin-spring-24.3.10.jar!/:na]
        at com.vaadin.flow.spring.VaadinServletContextInitializer$CompositeServletContextListener.lambda$contextInitialized$0(VaadinServletContextInitializer.java:223) ~[vaadin-spring-24.3.10.jar!/:na]
        at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1597) ~[na:na]
        at com.vaadin.flow.spring.VaadinServletContextInitializer$CompositeServletContextListener.contextInitialized(VaadinServletContextInitializer.java:223) ~[vaadin-spring-24.3.10.jar!/:na]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4451) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.23.jar!/:na]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:4887) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.23.jar!/:na]
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:171) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.23.jar!/:na]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1345) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.23.jar!/:na]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1335) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.23.jar!/:na]
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:317) ~[na:na]
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.InlineExecutorService.execute(InlineExecutorService.java:75) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.23.jar!/:na]
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(AbstractExecutorService.java:145) ~[na:na]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:876) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.23.jar!/:na]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.startInternal(StandardHost.java:845) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.23.jar!/:na]
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:171) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.23.jar!/:na]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1345) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.23.jar!/:na]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1335) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.23.jar!/:na]
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:317) ~[na:na]
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.InlineExecutorService.execute(InlineExecutorService.java:75) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.23.jar!/:na]
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(AbstractExecutorService.java:145) ~[na:na]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:876) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.23.jar!/:na]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal(StandardEngine.java:240) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.23.jar!/:na]
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:171) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.23.jar!/:na]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal(StandardService.java:470) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.23.jar!/:na]
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:171) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.23.jar!/:na]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.startInternal(StandardServer.java:947) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.23.jar!/:na]
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:171) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.23.jar!/:na]
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.Tomcat.start(Tomcat.java:437) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.23.jar!/:na]
        at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer.initialize(TomcatWebServer.java:126) ~[spring-boot-3.2.5.jar!/:3.2.5]
        at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer.<init>(TomcatWebServer.java:105) ~[spring-boot-3.2.5.jar!/:3.2.5]
        at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatServletWebServerFactory.getTomcatWebServer(TomcatServletWebServerFactory.java:499) ~[spring-boot-3.2.5.jar!/:3.2.5]
        at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatServletWebServerFactory.getWebServer(TomcatServletWebServerFactory.java:218) ~[spring-boot-3.2.5.jar!/:3.2.5]
        at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.createWebServer(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:188) ~[spring-boot-3.2.5.jar!/:3.2.5]
        at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.onRefresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:162) ~[spring-boot-3.2.5.jar!/:3.2.5]
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:618) ~[spring-context-6.1.6.jar!/:6.1.6]
        at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:146) ~[spring-boot-3.2.5.jar!/:3.2.5]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:754) ~[spring-boot-3.2.5.jar!/:3.2.5]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:456) ~[spring-boot-3.2.5.jar!/:3.2.5]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:334) ~[spring-boot-3.2.5.jar!/:3.2.5]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1354) ~[spring-boot-3.2.5.jar!/:3.2.5]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1343) ~[spring-boot-3.2.5.jar!/:3.2.5]
        at com.myexample.application.Application.main(Application.java:32) ~[!/:1.0.0]
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DirectMethodHandleAccessor.invoke(DirectMethodHandleAccessor.java:103) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:580) ~[na:na]
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.launch.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:91) ~[myexample-1.0.0.jar:1.0.0]
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.launch.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:53) ~[myexample-1.0.0.jar:1.0.0]
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.launch.JarLauncher.main(JarLauncher.java:58) ~[myexample-1.0.0.jar:1.0.0]
**Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: no DevModeHandlerManager implementation found but but dev server enabled. Either disable by setting vaadin.frontend.hotdeploy=false (and run the build-frontend maven goal) or include the vaadin-dev-server dependency**
        at com.vaadin.flow.spring.VaadinServletContextInitializer$DevModeServletContextListener.failFastContextInitialized(VaadinServletContextInitializer.java:490) ~[vaadin-spring-24.3.10.jar!/:na]
        at com.vaadin.flow.spring.VaadinServletContextInitializer$FailFastServletContextListener.contextInitialized(VaadinServletContextInitializer.java:195) ~[vaadin-spring-24.3.10.jar!/:na]
        ... 46 common frames omitted

2024-05-14T13:30:02.163+02:00 ERROR 21600 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext   : One or more listeners failed to start. Full details will be found in the appropriate container log file

Funny thing , looking on various threads about where they say it is just need to add in pom.xml file <frontendHotdeploy>false</frontendHotdeploy> , which I did but it keeps this error.
My pom.xml file is as follow, and as you can see there's the <frontendHotdeploy>false</frontendHotdeploy> , as like as they say in this thread: Cannot build to production in Vaadin 24 :
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <!-- Project from https://start.vaadin.com/project/9341ce37-5519-4679-9e05-365c2e9c9caf -->
    <groupId>com.myexample.application</groupId>
    <artifactId>myexample</artifactId>
    <name>myexample</name>
    <version>1.0.0</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
        <java.version>17</java.version>
        <maven-jar-plugin.version>3.4.1</maven-jar-plugin.version>
        <vaadin.version>24.3.11</vaadin.version>
        <tomcat.version>10.1.23</tomcat.version>
    </properties>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>3.2.5</version>
        <relativePath /> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>

    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>Vaadin Directory</id>
            <url>https://maven.vaadin.com/vaadin-addons</url>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>false</enabled>
            </snapshots>
        </repository>
    </repositories>

    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>com.vaadin</groupId>
                <artifactId>vaadin-bom</artifactId>
                <version>${vaadin.version}</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.vaadin</groupId>
            <!-- Replace artifactId with vaadin-core to use only free components -->
            <artifactId>vaadin</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.vaadin</groupId>
            <artifactId>vaadin-spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.parttio</groupId>
            <artifactId>line-awesome</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-validation</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <!-- <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency> -->
        <!-- <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency> -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>            
        </dependency>        
        <!-- <dependency>
            <groupId>com.vaadin</groupId>
            <artifactId>vaadin-testbench-junit5</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency> -->
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <defaultGoal>spring-boot:run</defaultGoal>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>com.vaadin</groupId>
                <artifactId>vaadin-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${vaadin.version}</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>build-frontend</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <phase>compile</phase>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
                <configuration>
                    <!-- To always force an optimized production bundle build set this configuration to 'true' -->
                    <!-- To possibly use the pre-compiled production bundle remove or set to 'false' -->
                    <forceProductionBuild>true</forceProductionBuild>
                    <frontendHotdeploy>false</frontendHotdeploy>                    
                    <!-- To have reproducible build by running 'npm ci' -->
                    <ciBuild>true</ciBuild>
                </configuration>                
            </plugin>          
        </plugins>
    </build>

    <profiles>
        <profile>
            <!-- Production mode is activated using -Pproduction -->
            <id>production</id>
            <dependencies>
                <!-- Exclude development dependencies from production -->
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>com.vaadin</groupId>
                    <artifactId>vaadin-core</artifactId>
                    <exclusions>
                        <exclusion>
                            <groupId>com.vaadin</groupId>
                            <artifactId>vaadin-dev</artifactId>
                        </exclusion>
                    </exclusions>
                </dependency>
            </dependencies>
            <build>
                <plugins>
                    <plugin>
                        <groupId>com.vaadin</groupId>
                        <artifactId>vaadin-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                        <version>${vaadin.version}</version>
                        <executions>
                            <execution>
                                <goals>
                                    <goal>build-frontend</goal>
                                </goals>
                                <phase>compile</phase>
                            </execution>
                        </executions>
                    </plugin>
                    <plugin>
                        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                        <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
                        <configuration>
                          <archive>
                            <manifest>
                              <addClasspath>true</addClasspath>
                              <classpathPrefix>target/classes/</classpathPrefix>
                              <mainClass>com.myexample.application.Application</mainClass>
                            </manifest>
                          </archive>
                        </configuration>
                    </plugin>                                          
                </plugins>
            </build>
        </profile>

        <profile>
            <id>it</id>
            <build>
                <plugins>
                    <plugin>
                        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                        <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                        <executions>
                            <execution>
                                <id>start-spring-boot</id>
                                <phase>pre-integration-test</phase>
                                <goals>
                                    <goal>start</goal>
                                </goals>
                            </execution>
                            <execution>
                                <id>stop-spring-boot</id>
                                <phase>post-integration-test</phase>
                                <goals>
                                    <goal>stop</goal>
                                </goals>
                            </execution>
                        </executions>
                    </plugin>
                </plugins>
            </build>
        </profile>

    </profiles>
</project>

I am using Vaadin 24.3.11, Tomcat Native 2.0.7 inside Tomcat 10.1.23 and in the system there are installed Java 17 and Java 22 (To run from command line it has to be executed from Java > 17 so I choosed to run frmo Java 22). In MANIFEST.MF I put:
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Build-Jdk-Spec: 17
Implementation-Title: myexample
Implementation-Version: 1.0.0
Main-Class: com.myexample.application.Application

so it should retrieve the Main Class to start with from browser...
Maybe did I missed something or there is something wrong in my pom.xml to not be run in properly way even it built successful?
Thanks to all in advance!
Cheers!
Luigi

Have you followed: https://vaadin.com/docs/latest/production/production-build

Yes, tried with mvn command and from Eclipse too , and both ways reports BUILD SUCCESS . , just if I try to run java -jar filename.jar --trace it reports error... even if I added that <frontendHotdeploy>false</frontendHotdeploy> as in this Vaadin thread they suggest to add https://vaadin.com/forum/t/cannot-build-for-production-vaadin-24/164771/35 ... so I was asking because maybe it could be related to Vaadin version or something else...

Hello @cfrick and everyone, after some more investigation I realized it wasn't really related to production profile activation which I activated it properly. But it looks it was missing to add prepare-frontend plugin too, so frontend would be added in jar file during compilation:
<plugin>
    <groupId>com.vaadin</groupId>
    <artifactId>vaadin-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>${vaadin.version}</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <goals>
                <goal>prepare-frontend</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>

and once added that due compiling first preparing the frontend and then building the frontend to be included in final jar file, then running the jar file worked like a charm! Just so it would help someone who would forget one of those two plugin blocks.... Thanks to all! Cheers!
